# Differentiating between adjective and adverb?

Tags: grammar

The sentence in question is this:

> 我的心又似小木船

it is translated: my heart is like a **small** wooden boat.

can it also mean: my heart is **a little bit** like a wooden boat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

我的心似小木船。
My heart is like a small wooden boat.

a little bit like would be 有点儿像

我的心有点儿像一艘小木船。